# 4 or more of the same consecutive letters

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone tell me what I can add to my existing RegEx expression so that 4 or more of the same letter consecutively is invalid? This is what I have so far:

```
(^[A-Za-z]{1})([A-Za-z\-\'\s]{0,})([A-Za-z]{1}$)
```

It meets all but 1 of my requirements so far which are:

- Any alphabetic character
- Single spaces but not as first or last character
- Hyphens but not as the first or last character
- Single quotes but not as the first or last character
- **No more than 3 consecutive characters the same, irrespective of case**
- At least 2 characters long, if present

Some examples:

```
James        - valid  
Sarah Jayne  - valid  
Michellle    - valid  
O'Brian      - valid  
Holly-Rose   - valid  
Eeeeric      - invalid  
Jo--anne     - invalid
```

Comment: Add valid and invalid samples

Comment: It's for name validation so:
Ashley - valid  
James - valid  
Jo-Michelle - valid  
Jeeeerry - invalid
O'Brian - valid
Emma Jayne - valid
Jo--Danielle - invalid

Comment: Read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) and reconsider whether you actually need this validation.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Do not validate names with a regular expression. Either allow **any** input, or at the very most perform some *very basic* validation such as "minimum length 3 characters".

Comment: Try [`^(?!.*(.)\1{3})[A-Za-z][A-Za-z' -]*[A-Za-z]$`](https://regex101.com/r/8YHsZQ/3) but it is not quite clear to me now. If only *letters* cannot be 4 consecutive ones, replace `(.)` with `([a-zA-Z])`

Comment: @Carpentweet `Jo--anne` is valid from your RegEx. So either you miss a constraint, either this name is a valid one : https://regex101.com/r/OKaxq3/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, edits and comment, you can probably use this regex in Javascript:

```
/^(?=.{2})(?!.*([a-z])\1{3})[a-z]+(?:[' -][a-z]+)*$/gmi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/01j83u/2)

There are 2 lookaheads:

- `(?=.{2})` - Positive lookahead to ensure there are at least 2 characters in input
- `(?!.*([a-z])\1{3})` Negative lookahead to ensure we don't allow 4 repeats of alphabets.